# awk's possibility of having the output reflect the input with regards to field separation

Tags: awk

I know that the default `FS` is `" "` (a single space) which is a special case and means "spaces, tabs, and newlines" and that the default `OFS` is `" "` (a single space).

Is it possible to know the exact string by which two specific fields have been separated, or more generally, have the output format reflect the input format in a way that given the input

```
$ cat foo
foo bar        quux  # single space, single tab
 foo  bar   quux     # single space, double space, triple space
```

the command:

```
$ awk '{ $2 = "blah" }1' foo
```

would yield:

```
foo blah        quux  # single space, single tab
 foo  blah   quux     # single space, double space, triple space
```

instead of:

```
foo blah quux         # single space, single space according to default OFS
foo blah quux         # single space, single space according to default OFS
```

Comment: I executed your awk line with your input. my awk (gawk) gave the output as you expected. (single space separated)

Comment: @Kent You misunderstood my question, I am asking if there is a way to get the first output (individual output field separators = individual input field separators).

Comment: oh, sorry about that... ..

Comment: I think you can do it with `awk 'BEGIN {FS="[ ]"} { $2 = "blah" }1' foo` as seen on http://awk.freeshell.org/FS

Comment: @fedorqui That just sets `FS` to an actual single space (instead of any whitespace) which [does not yield](http://pastebin.com/Fm9syFdQ) what I am looking for :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sub` , `gsub` or `gensub` could work in this case, but only do this on `$0`, don't do it on `$1-n`, because it won't trigger recalculate OFS.

but you have to calculate the spaces/tabs, to write the regex pattern, in order to make sure the substitution replacing the right text part (field) in your line. (like @Ed shown)

If you have gawk, you could use `FPAT`, it could save some effort by:

```
 awk  'BEGIN{FPAT="\\s*\\S*\\s*";OFS=""} {sub("\\S*","bar",$2)}1' file
```

this generates the result you wanted.

e.g.: (the `<tab>` cannot be seen, but it is there)

```
kent$  cat file
foo bar qq
 foo  bar   qqq
kent$  awk  'BEGIN{FPAT="\\s*\\S*\\s*";OFS=""} {sub("\\S*","xxx",$2)}1' file
foo xxx qq
 foo  xxx   qqq
```

Comment: +1 for the solution. If you change the sub() to use RE delimiters instead of string delimiters then you don't need to double-escape the "\S": `sub(/\S*/,..)`. I don't think you need the trailing \\s* on the FPAT though, see @sudo_O's solution.

Comment: @EdMorton yep, the trailing `\s*` could be saved.

Answer (score 3):

You CANNOT assign a value to a field without awk recompiling the record using the value of OFS as the separator. Instead, use a regexp to describe the whole record and replace the part of the record that exists where the field you care about exists. e.g. with GNU awk (in other awks - use match()/substr() and [[:space:]]):

```
$ cat foo
foo bar quux         # single space, single tab
 foo  bar   quux     # single space, double space, triple space

$ awk '{ print gensub(/^(\s*(\S+\s+){1})\S+(.*)/,"\\1blah\\3","") }' foo
foo blah quux         # single space, single tab
 foo  blah   quux     # single space, double space, triple space
```

Change the `1` in `{1}` to suit however many fields precede the field you want to replace:

```
$ awk '{ print gensub(/^(\s*(\S+\s+){2})\S+(.*)/,"\\1blah\\3","") }' foo
foo bar blah         # single space, single tab
 foo  bar   blah     # single space, double space, triple space

$ awk '{ print gensub(/^(\s*(\S+\s+){3})\S+(.*)/,"\\1blah\\3","") }' foo
foo bar quux         blah single space, single tab
 foo  bar   quux     blah single space, double space, triple space
```

gawk also contains a function named patsplit() which works like split() but instead of only storing the fields in the resultant string, it also stores the spaces between the fields in a second array so you can use a loop on those arrays to get the original spaces if that's clearer:

```
$ awk '{ nf = patsplit($0,fld,/\S+/,sep); fld[2]="blah"; for (i=1;i<=nf;i++) printf "%s%s", sep[i-1], fld[i]; print "" }' foo
foo blah quux         # single space, single tab
 foo  blah   quux     # single space, double space, triple space

$ awk '{ nf = patsplit($0,fld,/\S+/,sep); fld[3]="blah"; for (i=1;i<=nf;i++) printf "%s%s", sep[i-1], fld[i]; print "" }' foo
foo bar blah         # single space, single tab
 foo  bar   blah     # single space, double space, triple space
```

Here's how patsplit() is breaking down each record:

```
$ awk '{ nf = patsplit($0,fld,/\S+/,sep); print "\n" $0; for (i=0;i<=nf;i++) print "<" i ":" fld[i]
 ":" sep[i] ">" }' foo

foo bar quux         # single space, single tab
<0::>
<1:foo: >
<2:bar: >
<3:quux:         >
<4:#: >
<5:single: >
<6:space,: >
<7:single: >
<8:tab:>

 foo  bar   quux     # single space, double space, triple space
<0:: >
<1:foo:  >
<2:bar:   >
<3:quux:     >
<4:#: >
<5:single: >
<6:space,: >
<7:double: >
<8:space,: >
<9:triple: >
<10:space:>
```

Comment: You mean, "without awk recompiling the record using the value of *O*FS"? I was afraid the answer would be "no". I am well aware that I can use a regex to describe the whole record, but the point was not to have to do that, which is really awkward with complex `FS`es since that itself can be a regex and it would have been neat to be able to do the above :(

Comment: Thanks for the elaborate input, I didn't know about `patsplit` - very informative!

Answer (score 2):

There is no general solution to this problem but if you have `GNU awk` you can do this by being clever with `FPAT` by including the leading whitespace as part of the field:

```
$ awk '{sub(/\S+/,"blah",$2)}1' OFS= FPAT='\\s*\\S+' file
foo blah quux         # single space single tab
 foo  blah   quux     # single space double space triple space
```

The method is problem specific, the regexps for the substitution and `FPAT` would need altering for each problem but you can't do much better with `awk`.

Comment: +1 for the solution but why not use `sub(/\S+/...)` and `FPAT='\\s*\\S+'` so it works for all space-separated fields?

Comment: @EdMorton you already got +1 from me for `patsplit` I originally thought about using `split()` twice to do this but the optional leading whitespace messes that up.

Comment: Glad you fixed the regex so it actually works with my provided input, now I can upvote without feeling bad :-)